# Matlab parallel writes and read

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I have a parfor loop, but each loop reads from common sources array `UM` and `Temp`, and writes to a common cell `PMatrix`. Will this cause a bottle neck problem? and how can I avoid that? Thanks.

```
parfor i = 1:um_Elements
    for j = 1:Temp_Elements
        ind = (i-1)*Temp_Elements + j;
        u = UM(i);
        SS();
        tem = Temp(j);
        PMatrix{i,j}(1) = u;
        PMatrix{i,j}(2) = tem;
    end
end
```

Also, when using two workers, the performance is improved by 2. But when using 16 workers, the performance does not change much. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, `UM`, `Temp` and `PMatrix` are all [*sliced*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variables.html) variables. This means that the `parfor` machinery can see that those variables are operated on in independent sections (known as "slices") by the workers, and so only the required portions are transferred from the client to the workers.

As to why adding more workers doesn't lead to additional speed improvements - it's possible that you simply aren't doing something computationally intensive enough in the body of the loop to overcome the overhead of transferring the data.

Comment: Thanks. I have another question about this. I am doing ~13,000 `(i,j)`'s, but so far I can only do `parfor` for the outer loop. Is there a way to do  `parfor` for the inner loop as well so that I can fully distribute the 13,000 calculations to my workers? Thanks.

Comment: `parfor` can only operate at one level of parallelism. If your code really is precisely as above, vectorisation is much more likely to give you speedup than `parfor`.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give some recommendation on how to do vectorisation? Thanks.